# Tail recursion in scala ,here I am running scala code in eclipse IDE ,but getting no output

Tags: eclipse, scala, recursion, tail-recursion

```
object TailRec extends App {
  def anotherFactorial(x: Int): BigInt = {
    @tailrec
    def helperFact(n: Int, accu: BigInt): BigInt =
      if(n <= 1)
        accu
      else
        helperFact(n-1, n * accu)

    helperFact(x, 1)
  }

  println(anotherFactorial(5000)) // I want output but in console no output is printed
}
```

Comment: works for me, how are you running this?

Comment: thank you  for editing ,I  am running using eclise IDE Oxygen version 4.

Comment: Does Eclipse ask you for a main class? Do you have TailRec set as your main class?

Comment: Are you sure that the recursive function is the problem? What happens if you call `anotherFactorial` outside this object? What happens if you just put `println("Hello")` in your `TailRec` object? Try to create the simplest piece of code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons why this is not working (neither of which relates to recursive functions).

If this is intended to be the entry point of the program then the problem is that Eclipse is not configured to use `TailRec` as the entry point. If you are not getting a warning from Eclipse then you probably have another entry point that is being used by default (e.g. an `object Main extends App`). You need to configure Eclipse to use `TailRec` as the entry point object.

If this is intended to be an object in an application with a different entry point then the problem is that it extends `App` which does weird things to the way that an object is initialised. Remove this super class and call `anotherFactorial` and it should run your `println` statement. (You need to do call a method or inspect a value in an object in order for it to be initialised)

In both cases you can test this with a simple `println` in the `object` because the recursive factorial function is not relevant (and works fine!)